# Conformal transformation: electric field of dipole

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, conformal-field-theory, dipole

In beautiful paper ([open access](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/12/9/093030/meta)) authors calculate analytically optical response of "kissing" nanowires. Authors use method of "conformal transformation".

Firstly, authors consider dipole (dipole moment $\Delta$) between two infinite metal slabs. Authors then consider "kissing" nanowires using conformal transformation of complex coordinate $z = x + i y$ (and $z* = x - i y$) to new coordinate sysem $z'$ via map (Eq. 1 of authors)

$z' = \frac{g^2}{z*}$,

$g$ constant. Authors immeadiately write down electric field of dipole after conformal transformation (Eq. 4 of authors)

$\boldsymbol{E}_0 = \frac{1}{2 \pi \epsilon} \frac{\Delta}{g^2}$

Question: How to derive this simple result? Where does it come from? Is it obvious?

Comment: It seems that eq. (4) is taken as a definition of $\boldsymbol \Delta$. For one thing, that equation is **not** the electric field of an electric dipole with moment $\boldsymbol \Delta$. Moreover, the true dipole moment considered by the authors is $\boldsymbol p$ (eq.24), which can be obtained from $\boldsymbol\Delta$.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks.  Authors state above Eq. 4 "The original dipole ∆ is transformed into a uniform electric field, which we will take as due to an incident plane wave under the electrostatic approximation". What it means dipole is transformed into a E-field? Why take as incident plane wave? Does it make senses to you?